# Automapper dbNull StrongTypingException

Tags: c#, ms-access, automapper

I am using `Automapper` to read an access db. Reading strings, and getting the exception:

```
System.Data.StrongTypingException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146232021
Message=The value for column 'MapBook' in table 'tblBidSetup' is DBNull.
```

It is a string, so definitely `nullable`. Any idea how to avoid this exception?

Answer (score -1):

Use try catch in automapper to bypass error

Comment: I'm not going to edit Automapper source code, but rather assume that I'm doing something incorrect.